# tensorflow to deal with variable length of text

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I am planing implement an RNN, when I tried to do preprocessing, there is one problem, I used `VocabularyProcessor`to do the convert number of my text content. For example, I have a list of text:

```
a = ['I am yours','you are','today is friday']
vocab_processor = learn.preprocessing.VocabularyProcessor(3)
print (x_train)
```

the result is:

```
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 0]
 [6 7 8]]
```

Actually, I only want the second line is [4,5] without 0
For example, if two new texts come in `b = ['tomorrow is a good friday','you']` I hope the results are:

```
[[0 7 0 0 8]
 [4]]
```

rather than `np.array(list(vocab_processor.transform(b)))` which is:

```
[[0 7 0]
 [4 0 0]]
```

any idea?

Comment: Have you considered using tf.where to filter out zeros from your vocab_processor ?

Comment: but if I filter out 0, <UNK> token also will be filtered. because the padding tokens and <UNK> token are both 0

Comment: In an RNN you will generally 0-pad, and also pass in a 0/1 mask array to indicate which values are 0-padded and which are not. You'll want to use the dynamic_rnn which supports this. What it's doing under the covers is computing the 0-padded values, but then multiplying the loss function by 0, resulting in a 0-gradient which has no effect. The problem with not zero-padding is that you can run efficient bulk matrix operations, so that's just not supported.